# How to replace or newly install Ubuntu Desktop by removing already existing Ubuntu Server

Tags: server

I would like to know, how to remove already installed Ubuntu Server completely and install Ubuntu  Desktop through USB Stick. Here I do not have any other OS installed on my Machine. I only have Ubuntu Server. Please help.

I appreciate your time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To install Ubuntu you'll need any software that makes bootable USB sticks.Ex: `Rufus` and `Win2Flash` for windows and `Disk Image Writer`(by right clicking on iso file and open with Disk Image Writer.) in Ubuntu.
Once you have Bootable USB you need to restart your machine and got to boot menu. Select `Boot from USB`(Usb name) from the available options.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu you will be asked if you want to format and partition the disk(s).  Answer yes to that question and anything that was previously on those drives will be gone.

It's been a while since I did a clean install so I'm not sure of the install steps order.  If you are asked if you want the machine to be dual boot, answer no.